# Entity Framework: association between two edmx models

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, foreign-keys, edmx-designer

I have a bigger project that uses multiple edmx files to manage the data model for an asp.net application. What I want to achieve is to link two entities accross two edmx models.
So basically, just a foreign key like this: EntityA.ForeignEntityId --> EntityB.Id
However, since the enitites are not in the same model, I cannot add this foreign key in the model designer. I know that I could do it manually by either modifying the auto-generated SQL-file or by adding the relation in the SQL Server Manager. Both these approaches have the massive downside that they are not easily maintainable because if I do "Create database from model" and run the resulting SQL script, my manual modifications are dropped (I thnink?).
So is there a way of referencing a foreign entity from another edmx model in the model designer?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but i found myself with the same problem. If you create the reference in SQL and update your model from the database it will pull in the table that is referenced. I don't think this really solves the problem we have but it will at least allow for you to go back and forth without losing any FKs.